# Find the longest arithmetic expression with value equal to number of letters in its english representation

Tags: calculation-puzzle, optimization

The expression "twenty minus five" has 15 letters (we ignore spaces) and also has the arithmetic value of 15.

You can use standard math constants, operators and functions, represented by English words. Spaces and parenthesis do not count towards the expression length.

Find the longest such expression.

> EDIT: As correctly stated in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6304/7403, no such expression exists, so only the bonus now remains.

As a bonus, find the most interesting such expression.

Comment: how about a variation where the same word cannot be used more than once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no determinate result to this question.

> plus twenty minus two: equals 18, 18 letters
>
> plus twenty minus two plus twenty minus two: equals 36, 36 letters
>
> plus twenty minus two plus twenty minus two plus twenty minus two: equals 54, 54 letters

and so on...

Comment: Another answer gave infinity, and it was around 2 minutes earlier. That one should be accepted.

Comment: There is no obligation to accept the first correct answer. I suggest people accept whatever answer they think is best.

Comment: I would say, the answer which best *explains* things should become the accepted answer.

Comment: And I think `infinity` is not a correct answer. The correct answer does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

4 + (1x21) = 25

Four plus (one times twenty one) = 25 characters

Then continue adding `+ (1x21)` to the equation:

4 + (1x21) + (1x21) = 46

Four plus (one times twenty one) plus (one times twenty one) = 46 characters

4 + (1x21) + (1x21) + (1x21) = 67

Four plus (one times twenty one) plus (one times twenty one) plus (one times twenty one) = 67 characters.

You can keep doing this forever, so the answer is **infinity**.

Answer (score 3):

The "most interesting" is a little bit subjective. I will try my best, though.

> `the square root of six to the fourth` $=36$
>
> `minus e to the i pi plus two to the fourth times four minus two` $=63$*
>
> `one fourth of six to the third minus eleven` $=43$

More will surely follow when found.

<sub>*Follow order of operations and this evaluates to 1 + (4*16) - 2</sub>

Answer (score 2):

So I'll start with this:

`One billion to the one billionth power` has 32 characters. We'll call this string `POWER`. We'll refer to the value `1000000000^1000000000` as the constant `BTB`.

`plus three minus two minus one` has 25 characters. This evaluates to 0. We'll call this string `MINUS`.

`plus one plus six plus seven plus fifty` has 32 characters. This evaluates to 64. We'll call this string `PLUS`

If we place the `POWER` string, contact the `MINUS` string a number of times equal to `BTB / 25` then we will have a string of length BTB + 32 and a value of BTB. We then add the string `PLUS` to the end, and we have a length of BTB + 64 and a value of BTB + 64.

For the sake of stack exchange's servers, I have only *defined* the string, not actually written the string out.

You can repeat this process ad infinitum by tacking `to the twenty billionth power` to the end of the `POWER` string, and adding the appropriate number of `MINUS` strings to compensate, since they both have 25 CAREacaters (that's characters we care about. Clever, no?) Remember that now that BTB has increased, we still put the `MINUS` string BTB times, but we also remove an additional `MINUS` string for every additional `to the twenty billionth power` because we don't need to compensate for that anymore.

Comment: Added bonus: this is probably extendable pretty easily - one power of 10 string with *x* number of characters, then another string with value *2x* and *x* characters.

Comment: Yep, I was busy working on that. I chose one that conveniently fit into 25 characters so it could fit into the framework of using my `MINUS` string.