# Longest arithmetic expression where the answer is equal to the number of letters

Tags: open-ended, calculation-puzzle

You can use any mathematical operations represented by English words. These English words must be found in a commonly used dictionary.

Spaces are neither letters nor words.

You can not use the same word twice. No numerical digits are allowed.

Example:

> Five plus eight
>
> Is 13, and it has 13 letters.

You objective is to find the longest expression

Inspired by: [Find the longest arithmetic expression with value equal to number of letters in its english representation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/find-the-longest-arithmetic-expression-with-value-equal-to-number-of-letters-in/6303)
To clarify, the difference here is that you can't repeat a word.

**Note:** *Your full expression must be stated as a whole in your answer. Therefore there's no infinite letter solutions.*

Comment: Infinite equals PHP ;)

Comment: Please set a standard: Would 21 be hyphenated or not? (I.E., does it count as one word or two?)

Comment: Are you allowed to be verbose in the answers? Are you allowed to use an 'equals' to have two sides of the equation equal the same value?

Comment: The latest monster uses every number from $0$ to $99$ inclusive. Anything with a higher score must have either: longer names for very large numbers OR more non-number words like the names or constants or more verbose means to say the same thing à la "multiplied with" instead of "times".

Comment: @warspyking 5000 rep exactly... I'm not going to ruin it :)

Comment: Many moons ago, I wrote a VBA script to spell out numbers in English. It was insanely helpful in finding solutions.

Comment: @mdc32 Soes ruin it mean an upvote or a downvote? Lol

Comment: Either one - an upvote in this case though.

Comment: @mdc32 uh oh, it's ruined. Upvote and make it an even number :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### <strike>1,720</strike> $\Rightarrow$ <strike>4,242</strike> $\Rightarrow$  24,749

This can be expanded infinitely so long as we can come up with new names for large numbers. In fact, notice that it starts with a new prefix after $10^{3,000}$. You could do the whole list again with the Milli- prefix and then Billi-, Trilli-, etc.

```
A Million Billion Trillion Quadrillion Quintillion Sextillion Septillion Octillion Nonillion Decillion Undecillion Duodecillion Tredecillion Quattuordecillion Quindecillion Sedecillion Septendecillion Octodecillion Novendecillion Vigintillion Unvigintillion Duovigintillion Tresvigintillion Quattuorvigintillion Quinvigintillion Sesvigintillion Septemvigintillion Octovigintillion Novemvigintillion Trigintillion Untrigintillion Duotrigintillion Trestrigintillion Quattuortrigintillion Quintrigintillion Sestrigintillion Septentrigintillion Octotrigintillion Noventrigintillion Quadragintillion Unquadragintillion Duoquadragintillion Tresquadragintillion Quattuorquadragintillion Quindragintillion Sesquadragintillion Septenquadragintillion Octoquadragintillion Novenquadragintillion Quinquagintillion Unquinquagintillion Duoquinquagintillion Tresquinquagintillion Quattuorquinquagintillion Quinquinquagintillion Sesquinquagintillion Septenquinquagintillion Octoquinquagintillion Novenquinquagintillion Sexagintillion Unsexagintillion Duosexagintillion Tresexagintillion Quattuorsexagintillion Quinsexagintillion Sesexagintillion Septensexagintillion Octosexagintillion Novensexagintillion Septuagintillion Unseptuagintillion Duoseptuagintillion Treseptuagintillion Quattuorseptuagintillion Quinseptuagintillion Seseptuagintillion Septenseptuagintillion Octoseptuagintillion Novenseptuagintillion Octogintillion Unoctogintillion Duooctogintillion Tresoctogintillion Quattuoroctogintillion Quinoctogintillion Sexoctogintillion Septemoctogintillion Octooctogintillion Novemoctogintillion Nonagintillion Unnonagintillion Duononagintillion Trenonagintillion Quattuornonagintillion Quinnonagintillion Senonagintillion Septenonagintillion Octononagintillion Novenonagintillion Centillion Uncentillion Duocentillion Trescentillion Quattuorcentillion Quincentillion Sexcentillion Septencentillion Octocentillion Novencentillion Decicentillion Undecicentillion Duodecicentillion Tredecicentillion Quattuordecicentillion Quindecicentillion Sedecicentillion Septendecicentillion Octodecicentillion Novendecicentillion Viginticentillion Unviginticentillion Duoviginticentillion Tresviginticentillion Quattuorviginticentillion Quinviginticentillion Sesviginticentillion Septemviginticentillion Octoviginticentillion Novemviginticentillion Trigintacentillion Untrigintacentillion Duotrigintacentillion Trestrigintacentillion Quattuortrigintacentillion Quintrigintacentillion Sestrigintacentillion Septentrigintacentillion Octotrigintacentillion Noventrigintacentillion Quadragintacentillion Unquadragintacentillion Duoquadragintacentillion Tresquadragintacentillion Quattuorquadragintacentillion Quinquadragintacentillion Sesquadragintacentillion Septenquadragintacentillion Octoquadragintacentillion Novenquadragintacentillion Quinquagintacentillion Unquinquagintacentillion Duoquinquagintacentillion Tresquinquagintacentillion Quattuorquinquagintacentillion Quinquinquagintacentillion Sesquinquagintacentillion Septenquinquagintacentillion Octoquinquagintacentillion Novenquinquagintacentillion Sexagintacentillion Unsexagintacentillion Duosexagintacentillion Tresexagintacentillion Quattuorsexagintacentillion Quinsexagintacentillion Sesexagintacentillion Septensexagintacentillion Octosexagintacentillion Novensexagintacentillion Septuagintacentillion Unseptuagintacentillion Duoseptuagintacentillion Treseptuagintacentillion Quattuorseptuagintacentillion Quinseptuagintacentillion Seseptuagintacentillion Septenseptuagintacentillion Octoseptuagintacentillion Novenseptuagintacentillion Octogintacentillion Unoctogintacentillion Duooctogintacentillion Tresoctogintacentillion Quattuoroctogintacentillion Quinoctogintacentillion Sexoctogintacentillion Septemoctogintacentillion Octooctogintacentillion Novemoctogintacentillion Nonagintacentillion Unnonagintacentillion Duononagintacentillion Trenonagintacentillion Quattuornonagintacentillion Quinnonagintacentillion Senonagintacentillion Septenonagintacentillion Octononagintacentillion Novenonagintacentillion Ducentillion Unducentillion Duoducentillion Treducentillion Quattuorducentillion Quinducentillion Seducentillion Septenducentillion Octoducentillion Novenducentillion Deciducentillion Undeciducentillion Duodeciducentillion Tredeciducentillion Quattuordeciducentillion Quindeciducentillion Sedeciducentillion Septendeciducentillion Octodeciducentillion Novendeciducentillion Vigintiducentillion Unvigintiducentillion Duovigintiducentillion Tresvigintiducentillion Quattuorvigintiducentillion Quinvigintiducentillion Sesvigintiducentillion Septemvigintiducentillion Octovigintiducentillion Novemvigintiducentillion Trigintaducentillion Untrigintaducentillion Duotrigintaducentillion Trestrigintaducentillion Quattuortrigintaducentillion Quintrigintaducentillion Sestrigintaducentillion Septentrigintaducentillion Octotrigintaducentillion Noventrigintaducentillion Quadragintaducentillion Unquadragintaducentillion Duoquadragintaducentillion Tresquadragintaducentillion Quattuorquadragintaducentillion Quinquadragintaducentillion Sesquadragintaducentillion Septenquadragintaducentillion Octoquadragintaducentillion Novenquadragintaducentillion Quinquagintaducentillion Unquinquagintaducentillion Duoquinquagintaducentillion Tresquinquagintaducentillion Quattuorquinquagintaducentillion Quinquinquagintaducentillion Sesquinquagintaducentillion Septenquinquagintaducentillion Octoquinquagintaducentillion Novenquinquagintaducentillion Sexagintaducentillion Unsexagintaducentillion Duosexagintaducentillion Tresexagintaducentillion Quattuorsexagintaducentillion Quinsexagintaducentillion Sesexagintaducentillion Septensexagintaducentillion Octosexagintaducentillion Novensexagintaducentillion Septuagintaducentillion Unseptuagintaducentillion Duoseptuagintaducentillion Treseptuagintaducentillion Quattuorseptuagintaducentillion Quinseptuagintaducentillion Seseptuagintaducentillion Septenseptuagintaducentillion Octoseptuagintaducentillion Novenseptuagintaducentillion Octogintaducentillion Unoctogintaducentillion Duooctogintaducentillion Tresoctogintaducentillion Quattuoroctogintaducentillion Quinoctogintaducentillion Sexoctogintaducentillion Septemoctogintaducentillion Octooctogintaducentillion Novemoctogintaducentillion Nonagintaducentillion Unnonagintaducentillion Duononagintaducentillion Trenonagintaducentillion Quattuornonagintaducentillion Quinnonagintaducentillion Senonagintaducentillion Septenonagintaducentillion Octononagintaducentillion Novenonagintaducentillion Trecentillion Untrecentillion Duotrecentillion Trestrecentillion Quattuortrecentillion Quintrecentillion Sestrecentillion Septentrecentillion Octotrecentillion Noventrecentillion Decitrecentillion Undecitrecentillion Duodecitrecentillion Tredecitrecentillion Quattuordecitrecentillion Quindecitrecentillion Sedecitrecentillion Septendecitrecentillion Octodecitrecentillion Novendecitrecentillion Vigintitrecentillion Unvigintitrecentillion Duovigintitrecentillion Tresvigintitrecentillion Quattuorvigintitrecentillion Quinvigintitrecentillion Sesvigintitrecentillion Septemvigintitrecentillion Octovigintitrecentillion Novemvigintitrecentillion Trigintatrecentillion Untrigintatrecentillion Duotrigintatrecentillion Trestrigintatrecentillion Quattuortrigintatrecentillion Quintrigintatrecentillion Sestrigintatrecentillion Septentrigintatrecentillion Octotrigintatrecentillion Noventrigintatrecentillion Quadragintatrecentillion Unquadragintatrecentillion Duoquadragintatrecentillion Tresquadragintatrecentillion Quattuorquadragintatrecentillion Quinquadragintatrecentillion Sesquadragintatrecentillion Septenquadragintatrecentillion Octoquadragintatrecentillion Novenquadragintatrecentillion Quinquagintatrecentillion Unquinquagintatrecentillion Duoquinquagintatrecentillion Tresquinquagintatrecentillion Quattuorquinquagintatrecentillion Quinquinquagintatrecentillion Sesquinquagintatrecentillion Septenquinquagintatrecentillion Octoquinquagintatrecentillion Novenquinquagintatrecentillion Sexagintatrecentillion Unsexagintatrecentillion Duosexagintatrecentillion Tresexagintatrecentillion Quattuorsexagintatrecentillion Quinsexagintatrecentillion Sesexagintatrecentillion Septensexagintatrecentillion Octosexagintatrecentillion Novensexagintatrecentillion Septuagintatrecentillion Unseptuagintatrecentillion Duoseptuagintatrecentillion Treseptuagintatrecentillion Quattuorseptuagintatrecentillion Quinseptuagintatrecentillion Seseptuagintatrecentillion Septenseptuagintatrecentillion Octoseptuagintatrecentillion Novenseptuagintatrecentillion Octogintatrecentillion Unoctogintatrecentillion Duooctogintatrecentillion Tresoctogintatrecentillion Quattuoroctogintatrecentillion Quinoctogintatrecentillion Sexoctogintatrecentillion Septemoctogintatrecentillion Octooctogintatrecentillion Novemoctogintatrecentillion Nonagintatrecentillion Unnonagintatrecentillion Duononagintatrecentillion Trenonagintatrecentillion Quattuornonagintatrecentillion Quinnonagintatrecentillion Senonagintatrecentillion Septenonagintatrecentillion Octononagintatrecentillion Novenonagintatrecentillion Quadringentillion Unquadringentillion Duoquadringentillion Tresquadringentillion Quattuorquadringentillion Quinquadringentillion Sesquadringentillion Septenquadringentillion Octoquadringentillion Novenquadringentillion Deciquadringentillion Undeciquadringentillion Duodeciquadringentillion Tredeciquadringentillion Quattuordeciquadringentillion Quindeciquadringentillion Sedeciquadringentillion Septendeciquadringentillion Octodeciquadringentillion Novendeciquadringentillion Vigintiquadringentillion Unvigintiquadringentillion Duovigintiquadringentillion Tresvigintiquadringentillion Quattuorvigintiquadringentillion Quinvigintiquadringentillion Sesvigintiquadringentillion Septemvigintiquadringentillion Octovigintiquadringentillion Novemvigintiquadringentillion Trigintaquadringentillion Untrigintaquadringentillion Duotrigintaquadringentillion Trestrigintaquadringentillion Quattuortrigintaquadringentillion Quintrigintaquadringentillion Sestrigintaquadringentillion Septentrigintaquadringentillion Octotrigintaquadringentillion Noventrigintaquadringentillion Quadragintaquadringentillion Unquadragintaquadringentillion Duoquadragintaquadringentillion Tresquadragintaquadringentillion Quattuorquadragintaquadringentillion Quinquadragintaquadringentillion Sesquadragintaquadringentillion Septenquadragintaquadringentillion Octoquadragintaquadringentillion Novenquadragintaquadringentillion Quinquagintaquadringentillion Unquinquagintaquadringentillion Duoquinquagintaquadringentillion Tresquinquagintaquadringentillion Quattuorquinquagintaquadringentillion Quinquinquagintaquadringentillion Sesquinquagintaquadringentillion Septenquinquagintaquadringentillion Octoquinquagintaquadringentillion Novenquinquagintaquadringentillion Sexagintaquadringentillion Unsexagintaquadringentillion Duosexagintaquadringentillion Tresexagintaquadringentillion Quattuorsexagintaquadringentillion Quinsexagintaquadringentillion Sesexagintaquadringentillion Septensexagintaquadringentillion Octosexagintaquadringentillion Novensexagintaquadringentillion Septuagintaquadringentillion Unseptuagintaquadringentillion Duoseptuagintaquadringentillion Treseptuagintaquadringentillion Quattuorseptuagintaquadringentillion Quinseptuagintaquadringentillion Seseptuagintaquadringentillion Septenseptuagintaquadringentillion Octoseptuagintaquadringentillion Novenseptuagintaquadringentillion Octogintaquadringentillion Unoctogintaquadringentillion Duooctogintaquadringentillion Tresoctogintaquadringentillion Quattuoroctogintaquadringentillion Quinoctogintaquadringentillion Sexoctogintaquadringentillion Septemoctogintaquadringentillion Octooctogintaquadringentillion Novemoctogintaquadringentillion Nonagintaquadringentillion Unnonagintaquadringentillion Duononagintaquadringentillion Trenonagintaquadringentillion Quattuornonagintaquadringentillion Quinnonagintaquadringentillion Senonagintaquadringentillion Septenonagintaquadringentillion Octononagintaquadringentillion Novenonagintaquadringentillion Quingentillion Unquingentillion Duoquingentillion Tresquingentillion Quattuorquingentillion Quinquingentillion Sesquingentillion Septenquingentillion Octoquingentillion Novenquingentillion Deciquingentillion Undeciquingentillion Duodeciquingentillion Tredeciquingentillion Quattuordeciquingentillion Quindeciquingentillion Sedeciquingentillion Septendeciquingentillion Octodeciquingentillion Novendeciquingentillion Vigintiquingentillion Unvigintiquingentillion Duovigintiquingentillion Tresvigintiquingentillion Quattuorvigintiquingentillion Quinvigintiquingentillion Sesvigintiquingentillion Septemvigintiquingentillion Octovigintiquingentillion Novemvigintiquingentillion Trigintaquingentillion Untrigintaquingentillion Duotrigintaquingentillion Trestrigintaquingentillion Quattuortrigintaquingentillion Quintrigintaquingentillion Sestrigintaquingentillion Septentrigintaquingentillion Octotrigintaquingentillion Noventrigintaquingentillion Quadragintaquingentillion Unquadragintaquingentillion Duoquadragintaquingentillion Tresquadragintaquingentillion Quattuorquadragintaquingentillion Quinquadragintaquingentillion Sesquadragintaquingentillion Septenquadragintaquingentillion Octoquadragintaquingentillion Novenquadragintaquingentillion Quinquagintaquingentillion Unquinquagintaquingentillion Duoquinquagintaquingentillion Tresquinquagintaquingentillion Quattuorquinquagintaquingentillion Quinquinquagintaquingentillion Sesquinquagintaquingentillion Septenquinquagintaquingentillion Octoquinquagintaquingentillion Novenquinquagintaquingentillion Sexagintaquingentillion Unsexagintaquingentillion Duosexagintaquingentillion Tresexagintaquingentillion Quattuorsexagintaquingentillion Quinsexagintaquingentillion Sesexagintaquingentillion Septensexagintaquingentillion Octosexagintaquingentillion Novensexagintaquingentillion Septuagintaquingentillion Unseptuagintaquingentillion Duoseptuagintaquingentillion Treseptuagintaquingentillion Quattuorseptuagintaquingentillion Quinseptuagintaquingentillion Seseptuagintaquingentillion Septenseptuagintaquingentillion Octoseptuagintaquingentillion Novenseptuagintaquingentillion Octogintaquingentillion Unoctogintaquingentillion Duooctogintaquingentillion Tresoctogintaquingentillion Quattuoroctogintaquingentillion Quinoctogintaquingentillion Sexoctogintaquingentillion Septemoctogintaquingentillion Octooctogintaquingentillion Novemoctogintaquingentillion Nonagintaquingentillion Unnonagintaquingentillion Duononagintaquingentillion Trenonagintaquingentillion Quattuornonagintaquingentillion Quinnonagintaquingentillion Senonagintaquingentillion Septenonagintaquingentillion Octononagintaquingentillion Novenonagintaquingentillion Sescentillion Unsescentillion Duosescentillion Tresescentillion Quattuorsescentillion Quinsescentillion Sesescentillion Septensescentillion Octosescentillion Novensescentillion Decisescentillion Undecisescentillion Duodecisescentillion Tredecisescentillion Quattuordecisescentillion Quindecisescentillion Sedecisescentillion Septendecisescentillion Octodecisescentillion Novendecisescentillion Vigintisescentillion Unvigintisescentillion Duovigintisescentillion Tresvigintisescentillion Quattuorvigintisescentillion Quinvigintisescentillion Sesvigintisescentillion Septemvigintisescentillion Octovigintisescentillion Novemvigintisescentillion Trigintasescentillion Untrigintasescentillion Duotrigintasescentillion Trestrigintasescentillion Quattuortrigintasescentillion Quintrigintasescentillion Sestrigintasescentillion Septentrigintasescentillion Octotrigintasescentillion Noventrigintasescentillion Quadragintasescentillion Unquadragintasescentillion Duoquadragintasescentillion Tresquadragintasescentillion Quattuorquadragintasescentillion Quinquadragintasescentillion Sesquadragintasescentillion Septenquadragintasescentillion Octoquadragintasescentillion Novenquadragintasescentillion Quinquagintasescentillion Unquinquagintasescentillion Duoquinquagintasescentillion Tresquinquagintasescentillion Quattuorquinquagintasescentillion Quinquinquagintasescentillion Sesquinquagintasescentillion Septenquinquagintasescentillion Octoquinquagintasescentillion Novenquinquagintasescentillion Sexagintasescentillion Unsexagintasescentillion Duosexagintasescentillion Tresexagintasescentillion Quattuorsexagintasescentillion Quinsexagintasescentillion Sesexagintasescentillion Septensexagintasescentillion Octosexagintasescentillion Novensexagintasescentillion Septuagintasescentillion Unseptuagintasescentillion Duoseptuagintasescentillion Treseptuagintasescentillion Quattuorseptuagintasescentillion Quinseptuagintasescentillion Seseptuagintasescentillion Septenseptuagintasescentillion Octoseptuagintasescentillion Novenseptuagintasescentillion Octogintasescentillion Unoctogintasescentillion Duooctogintasescentillion Tresoctogintasescentillion Quattuoroctogintasescentillion Quinoctogintasescentillion Sexoctogintasescentillion Septemoctogintasescentillion Octooctogintasescentillion Novemoctogintasescentillion Nonagintasescentillion Unnonagintasescentillion Duononagintasescentillion Trenonagintasescentillion Quattuornonagintasescentillion Quinnonagintasescentillion Senonagintasescentillion Septenonagintasescentillion Octononagintasescentillion Novenonagintasescentillion Septingentillion Unseptingentillion Duoseptingentillion Treseptingentillion Quattuorseptingentillion Quinseptingentillion Seseptingentillion Septenseptingentillion Octoseptingentillion Novenseptingentillion Deciseptingentillion Undeciseptingentillion Duodeciseptingentillion Tredeciseptingentillion Quattuordeciseptingentillion Quindeciseptingentillion Sedeciseptingentillion Septendeciseptingentillion Octodeciseptingentillion Novendeciseptingentillion Vigintiseptingentillion Unvigintiseptingentillion Duovigintiseptingentillion Tresvigintiseptingentillion Quattuorvigintiseptingentillion Quinvigintiseptingentillion Sesvigintiseptingentillion Septemvigintiseptingentillion Octovigintiseptingentillion Novemvigintiseptingentillion Trigintaseptingentillion Untrigintaseptingentillion Duotrigintaseptingentillion Trestrigintaseptingentillion Quattuortrigintaseptingentillion Quintrigintaseptingentillion Sestrigintaseptingentillion Septentrigintaseptingentillion Octotrigintaseptingentillion Noventrigintaseptingentillion Quadragintaseptingentillion Unquadragintaseptingentillion Duoquadragintaseptingentillion Tresquadragintaseptingentillion Quattuorquadragintaseptingentillion Quinquadragintaseptingentillion Sesquadragintaseptingentillion Septenquadragintaseptingentillion Octoquadragintaseptingentillion Novenquadragintaseptingentillion Quinquagintaseptingentillion Unquinquagintaseptingentillion Duoquinquagintaseptingentillion Tresquinquagintaseptingentillion Quattuorquinquagintaseptingentillion Quinquinquagintaseptingentillion Sesquinquagintaseptingentillion Septenquinquagintaseptingentillion Octoquinquagintaseptingentillion Novenquinquagintaseptingentillion Sexagintaseptingentillion Unsexagintaseptingentillion Duosexagintaseptingentillion Tresexagintaseptingentillion Quattuorsexagintaseptingentillion Quinsexagintaseptingentillion Sesexagintaseptingentillion Septensexagintaseptingentillion Octosexagintaseptingentillion Novensexagintaseptingentillion Septuagintaseptingentillion Unseptuagintaseptingentillion Duoseptuagintaseptingentillion Treseptuagintaseptingentillion Quattuorseptuagintaseptingentillion Quinseptuagintaseptingentillion Seseptuagintaseptingentillion Septenseptuagintaseptingentillion Octoseptuagintaseptingentillion Novenseptuagintaseptingentillion Octogintaseptingentillion Unoctogintaseptingentillion Duooctogintaseptingentillion Tresoctogintaseptingentillion Quattuoroctogintaseptingentillion Quinoctogintaseptingentillion Sexoctogintaseptingentillion Septemoctogintaseptingentillion Octooctogintaseptingentillion Novemoctogintaseptingentillion Nonagintaseptingentillion Unnonagintaseptingentillion Duononagintaseptingentillion Trenonagintaseptingentillion Quattuornonagintaseptingentillion Quinnonagintaseptingentillion Senonagintaseptingentillion Septenonagintaseptingentillion Octononagintaseptingentillion Novenonagintaseptingentillion Octingentillion Unoctingentillion Duooctingentillion Tresoctingentillion Quattuoroctingentillion Quinoctingentillion Sexoctingentillion Septemoctingentillion Octooctingentillion Novemoctingentillion Decioctingentillion Undecioctingentillion Duodecioctingentillion Tredecioctingentillion Quattuordecioctingentillion Quindecioctingentillion Sedecioctingentillion Septendecioctingentillion Octodecioctingentillion Novendecioctingentillion Vigintioctingentillion Unvigintioctingentillion Duovigintioctingentillion Tresvigintioctingentillion Quattuorvigintioctingentillion Quinvigintioctingentillion Sesvigintioctingentillion Septemvigintioctingentillion Octovigintioctingentillion Novemvigintioctingentillion Trigintaoctingentillion Untrigintaoctingentillion Duotrigintaoctingentillion Trestrigintaoctingentillion Quattuortrigintaoctingentillion Quintrigintaoctingentillion Sestrigintaoctingentillion Septentrigintaoctingentillion Octotrigintaoctingentillion Noventrigintaoctingentillion Quadragintaoctingentillion Unquadragintaoctingentillion Duoquadragintaoctingentillion Tresquadragintaoctingentillion Quattuorquadragintaoctingentillion Quinquadragintaoctingentillion Sesquadragintaoctingentillion Septenquadragintaoctingentillion Octoquadragintaoctingentillion Novenquadragintaoctingentillion Quinquagintaoctingentillion Unquinquagintaoctingentillion Duoquinquagintaoctingentillion Tresquinquagintaoctingentillion Quattuorquinquagintaoctingentillion Quinquinquagintaoctingentillion Sesquinquagintaoctingentillion Septenquinquagintaoctingentillion Octoquinquagintaoctingentillion Novenquinquagintaoctingentillion Sexagintaoctingentillion Unsexagintaoctingentillion Duosexagintaoctingentillion Tresexagintaoctingentillion Quattuorsexagintaoctingentillion Quinsexagintaoctingentillion Sesexagintaoctingentillion Septensexagintaoctingentillion Octosexagintaoctingentillion Novensexagintaoctingentillion Septuagintaoctingentillion Unseptuagintaoctingentillion Duoseptuagintaoctingentillion Treseptuagintaoctingentillion Quattuorseptuagintaoctingentillion Quinseptuagintaoctingentillion Seseptuagintaoctingentillion Septenseptuagintaoctingentillion Octoseptuagintaoctingentillion Novenseptuagintaoctingentillion Octogintaoctingentillion Unoctogintaoctingentillion Duooctogintaoctingentillion Tresoctogintaoctingentillion Quattuoroctogintaoctingentillion Quinoctogintaoctingentillion Sexoctogintaoctingentillion Septemoctogintaoctingentillion Octooctogintaoctingentillion Novemoctogintaoctingentillion Nonagintaoctingentillion Unnonagintaoctingentillion Duononagintaoctingentillion Trenonagintaoctingentillion Quattuornonagintaoctingentillion Quinnonagintaoctingentillion Senonagintaoctingentillion Septenonagintaoctingentillion Octononagintaoctingentillion Novenonagintaoctingentillion Nongentillion Unnongentillion Duonongentillion Trenongentillion Quattuornongentillion Quinnongentillion Senongentillion Septenongentillion Octonongentillion Novenongentillion Decinongentillion Undecinongentillion Duodecinongentillion Tredecinongentillion Quattuordecinongentillion Quindecinongentillion Sedecinongentillion Septendecinongentillion Octodecinongentillion Novendecinongentillion Vigintinongentillion Unvigintinongentillion Duovigintinongentillion Tresvigintinongentillion Quattuorvigintinongentillion Quinvigintinongentillion Sesvigintinongentillion Septemvigintinongentillion Octovigintinongentillion Novemvigintinongentillion Trigintanongentillion Untrigintanongentillion Duotrigintanongentillion Trestrigintanongentillion Quattuortrigintanongentillion Quintrigintanongentillion Sestrigintanongentillion Septentrigintanongentillion Octotrigintanongentillion Noventrigintanongentillion Quadragintanongentillion Unquadragintanongentillion Duoquadragintanongentillion Tresquadragintanongentillion Quattuorquadragintanongentillion Quinquadragintanongentillion Sesquadragintanongentillion Septenquadragintanongentillion Octoquadragintanongentillion Novenquadragintanongentillion Quinquagintanongentillion Unquinquagintanongentillion Duoquinquagintanongentillion Tresquinquagintanongentillion Quattuorquinquagintanongentillion Quinquinquagintanongentillion Sesquinquagintanongentillion Septenquinquagintanongentillion Octoquinquagintanongentillion Novenquinquagintanongentillion Sexagintanongentillion Unsexagintanongentillion Duosexagintanongentillion Tresexagintanongentillion Quattuorsexagintanongentillion Quinsexagintanongentillion Sesexagintanongentillion Septensexagintanongentillion Octosexagintanongentillion Novensexagintanongentillion Septuagintanongentillion Unseptuagintanongentillion Duoseptuagintanongentillion Treseptuagintanongentillion Quattuorseptuagintanongentillion Quinseptuagintanongentillion Seseptuagintanongentillion Septenseptuagintanongentillion Octoseptuagintanongentillion Novenseptuagintanongentillion Octogintanongentillion Unoctogintanongentillion Duooctogintanongentillion Tresoctogintanongentillion Quattuoroctogintanongentillion Quinoctogintanongentillion Sexoctogintanongentillion Septemoctogintanongentillion Octooctogintanongentillion Novemoctogintanongentillion Nonagintanongentillion Unnonagintanongentillion Duononagintanongentillion Trenonagintanongentillion Quattuornonagintanongentillion Quinnonagintanongentillion Senonagintanongentillion Septenonagintanongentillion Octononagintanongentillion Novenonagintanongentillion Millinillion Millimillion Millibillion Millitrillionths multiplied with the value of e raised to i times pi plus Legendre's Constant minus negative Twenty-four Thousand Seven Hundred Forty Nine
```

In numerical form, it can be expressed as:

$$\prod_{n=1}^{1,003}10^{3n}\div10^{3,012}*(e^{i\pi}+1)+24,749 $$

---

[Legendre's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant)

Comment: You could just cram in more numeric words by replacing the first bit with `sum of ... times 0 ...`. Sum is an arithmetic operation, and lets you list nearly arbitrary numbers.  Such as `sum of two halves, three thirds, four quarters, five fifths, six sixths, seven sevenths, etc...`

Comment: Would words like fifty-six, eighty-three etc be found in a commonly used dictionary?

Comment: if you **REALLY** wanna max it out, use [this site](http://www.olsenhome.com/bignumbers/) and pick the longest words from there. I am too lazy, and I am busy at work.

Comment: @Evert Do you accept Dictionary.com? It's *my* most commonly used dictionary. [Fifty-six](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fifty-six?s=t) and [eighty-three](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eighty-three?s=t) both have entries.

Comment: @JLee I actually had the word "One" in there twice, too. I've triple-checked this latest entry. Feel free to check behind me as I have obviously created errors in the past.

Comment: my excel formula says that it's now 4,238.   hmmmm sorry man, that chat is blocked here at my work. it says i am not logged in when i click that link, and won't let me talk! but no, the question only says to remove the spaces, right? also, we're def. bending the "These English words must be found in a commonly used dictionary." condition. Also, hyphens and apostrophes *ARE* part of words.

Comment: @JLee Ah, OK. I have been removing both hyphens and apostrophes as well. I.E., I have only been counting the characters.

Comment: @JLee What's your count now? (I dropped spaces but included hyphens and apostrophes and Word says 4,242.)

Answer (score 16):

How about

### 624

Before you read the **huge** number below, realize my strategy: I am creating a number so huge that it cannot be written out, BUT, at the end it is multiplied by zero, and then 624 is added.

I am sure that someone could use this same strategy to get a much larger (longer) number than this.

Also note that [the numbers twenty-one through ninety-nine are hyphenated](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g80.html), making each of them one word. Thus, the word twenty is not in the word twenty-one, and so on.

> **Absolute value of** ninety-nine centillion ninety-eight vigintillion
>   ninety-seven novemdecillion ninety-six octodecillion ninety-five
>   septendecillion ninety-four sexdecillion ninety-three quindecillion
>   ninety-two quattuordecillion ninety-one tredecillion ninety
>   duodecillion eighty-nine undecillion eighty-eight decillion
>   eighty-seven nonillion eighty-six octillion eighty-five septillion
>   eighty-four sextillion eighty-three quintillion eighty-two quadrillion
>   eighty-one trillion eighty billion seventy-nine million seventy-eight
>   thousand **multiplied by** seventy-seven googol to the seventy-six
>   googolplex power **minus** seventy-five over seventy-four score **times** zero
>   **plus** six hundred twenty-four

Comment: Nice one :) (Now who wants to check his work to make sure the characters are the right length lol)

Comment: I used a formula in Excel to calculate the length minus the spaces: =LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")). Otherwise it wouldn't have been fun!

Answer (score 11):

### 145 Points

> $$\lvert\frac{\sqrt{9^2}}{\frac{1}{8^3}}\rvert+11+(e^{i\pi}*\frac{18,000}{10})-\frac{2,674,000}{1,000}$$

In English, this can be described as:

> Absolute value of root nine squared divided by inverse eight cubed plus eleven and $e$ to $i$ $pi$ times eighteen thousand tenths minus two point six seven four million thousandths.

Without spaces, that transcription is 145 characters. Mathematically, it evaluates in the following manner:

> $$\lvert\frac{\sqrt{81}}{\frac{1}{512}}\rvert+11+(-1*1,800)-2,674$$
>
>  $$\lvert9*512\rvert+11-1,800-2,674$$
>
>  $$\lvert4,608\rvert-4,463=4,608-4,463=145$$

Comment: Wow......I give up (*bows down*)

Comment: "two point six seven four million thousandths"? I'm glad I never had you as a math teacher...

Comment: Jeez... I wanna know how you come up with this stuff!

Comment: You can stretch this a little further. Replace "eleven" with "one hundred forty three billion billionths" and "eighteen thousand tenths" with "nineteen thousand tenths"

Comment: using **and** for **plus**? it's not the same thing though

Comment: @frodoskywalker I could be making a mistake, but I calculate that change to give 176 characters but a mathematical equivalent of 177...

Comment: @JLee I'm not using **and** to mean plus. A plus B and C minus D. The B & C are grouped. I.E., A plus (B and C) minus D. If I was speaking, it might sound like "A plus B'n'C minus D".

Comment: @Engineer you're right, I forgot about the letter taken away by eighteen/nineteen.

Answer (score 4):

**95 Points**

> square root of a hundred times four plus eleven minus one multiplied by two where ten is substracted and five added (95 letters)

which value is:

> $\sqrt{100} \times 4 + 11 - 1 \times 2 - 10 + 5  = 95$

Answer (score 3):

**67 points**

My attempt:

> two squared, to the power of five, multiplied by itself, plus eight, minus sixty-nine

which value is:

> $((2^2)^5)^2 + 8 - 69 = 67$

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's actually infinite.
you can keep going forever using subtraction, here's an example.</strike>

one billion minus nine hundred ninety-nine million, nine hundred ninety-nine thousand, nine hundred.
^- equals 100, and has one hundred characters.

onehundredminusseventyfour is 26 characters and evaluates to 26. It wouldn't be hard to go beyond that.
onethousandminusninehundredsixtyfour is 36
Just for fun: <strike>thisstatementevaluatestothenumberonehundredfiveplusfortyexponentzero</strike>

105 + 40^0 = 106.


Come to think of it, this contest is going to end in an arbitrarily large number as the winning entry just because someone's going to figure out how to create a word problem with no repeating word, and then it's going to be a hassle reading through it to verify that it doesn't have any spelling, grammar, or punctuation errors while still using exactly one of each English word (which, I might add, is a constantly expanding language.)

inwabambuule,mysticallando'honeycombsandrabbits,atribeofpixieslives.Theyrequirethirtyonetrombones.spritesfromtheneighboringboroughneedtwohundredthree.howmanytotalmusicalinstrumentsareneeded?giveyouranswertonearesthundredthdecimalplace

with spaces:
in wabambuule, mystical land o' honeycombs and rabbits, a tribe of pixies lives. They require thirty one trombones. sprites from the neighboring borough need two hundred three. how many total musical instruments are needed? give your answer to nearest hundredth decimal place

a few notes: 
1. Yes, I made up a name but any word will fit there. 
2. There are still quite a few synonyms for fairies I can use to expand this.
3. I have any number of musical instruments to add.

You could also just say --------...---infinity, where you have an infinite number of negation operators (which don't count as a repeated word, and are not expressly forbidden, and are not expressly stated not to count), but I'm going to assume that's out of the bounds of the problem because the whole point was to remove some of the loopholes that made the original problem go infinite.

Comment: You can not use the same word twice

Comment: whoops! Guess I'll use this as a starting point then. If spaces don't count, what about commas? They're grammatically important.

Comment: Your example for 106 only has 68 characters in it. Have I missed something?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was using Notepad++ to count the number of characters and forgot to delete the previous example.

Comment: In your latest edit, you use "of" twice...

Comment: good catch. temporary fix.

Comment: Per the first line of the question, mathematical operations must be represented by English words. You can't use "-" to mean negative because "-" is not a word and, even if it was, you could only use it once. Your infinity idea is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

$\Large\infty {\rm\ Points}$

If acronyms are allowed, one could technically construct the infinite-point acronym "an AAPO plus one", where AAPO is a recursive acronym that stands for "an AAPO plus one".

I believe, given a sufficiently large team of lawyers, this could be proven to not violate the prohibition on repeated words nor the prohibition on using words not in the English language.

Comment: Y'know great questions often get ruined and labeled "Too broad" when people find loopholes such as these. I'm editing the question...

Comment: It's a gag answer anyway. ;)